# Split A String to N parts based on underscore(_)

Tags: sql-server

```
set @filename1  = '0_General_0_INV_57_xyz.xlsx';
```

I need output like `@name = xyz, @userid = 57, @type = INV` and so on.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

***First Create Custom Split function***

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @Seperator varchar(1))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@Seperator, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@Seperator, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END

Go
```

***Execute this -***

```
declare @filename1 varchar(100)
set @filename1  = '0_General_0_INV_57_xyz.xlsx';
select * from dbo.SplitString (@filename1, '_')
```

***If you have SQL Server 2016 and later then No Custom function is needed as SQL Server has inbuild function. STRING_SPLIT ***

```
declare @filename1 varchar(100)
set @filename1  = '0_General_0_INV_57_xyz.xlsx';

select * from STRING_SPLIT (@filename1, '_')
```

*Note: STRING_SPLIT function only supported by SQL Server 2016 or Later*

Comment: There are much better string split functions that don't use `while` loops.  This solution will be very slow.